# fetch data from text file in pyttsx python

Tags: python, linux, speech-recognition, pyttsx, wit.ai

Hello respected persons,

I am trying to fetch data from a external text file with `pyttsx` package of python language.

I will save text in txt file and how `pyttsx` can read that text from txt file and can speak?

I am trying to do like this,

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say("open file and read data from /users/exe/voice.txt")
engine.runAndWait()
engine.runAndWait()
```

how `pyttsx` can fetch and speak data of a text file ?

actually my real motto is using `wit.ai` with `pyttsx` how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself: I had to add two lines of code to open the file and read its lines into an array:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
with open('/Users/exepaul/Desktop/a.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
engine.say(lines)
engine.runAndWait()
engine.runAndWait()
```